# How do I find the application name to open a file using AppleScript?

Tags: applescript

I find the AppleScript method of opening a file convenient but often cannot guess at the application name to use when I do not want the default options.

As an example, I have installed [Foxit PDF Reader](https://www.foxitsoftware.com/products/pdf-reader/) to directly annotate a PDF.  I have not been able to guess what to use in the `open -a ??? my.pdf` command.

How could I find this for any general application?  Perhaps there is some way to get a list of all available options?

Comment: It's simply: `open -a "Foxit Reader" /path/to/file.pdf`

Comment: @user3439894, this resolves my example case but Mateusz's answer identifies how to apply this to the general case.  There are many applications I want to do this with and I do not want to ask a new question for each one.

Comment: As I never have to worry about Localization, I personally have no need to get the BundleIdentifier as I can plainly see the name of the Apps and all work of me as in the example I previously presented. Anyway, building on what Mateusz Szlosek presented, if you want to get all of the app names and BundleIdentifier in a nice list, just use the following command line. Copy and paste it into Terminal: `for f in /Applications/*.app; do echo "${f##*/} =>" "$(plutil -p "$f/Contents/Info.plist" | awk -F'[""]' '/BundleIdentifier/ {print $4}')"; done`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `-b` option and use Bundle Identifier instead of using Application name. For example, to get Bundle Identifier from **Safari**:

```
plutil -p /Applications/Safari.app/Contents/Info.plist | grep BundleIdentifier
```

as a result You'll get `"CFBundleIdentifier" => "com.apple.Safari"`

Then You use it like this:

```
open -b com.apple.Safari /path/to/file
```

Generally, You'll need to get Bundle Indentifier from `Info.plist` file located inside `Application.app/Contents/` directory.

Or if You want, You can get the app name with this:

```
plutil -p /Applications/PaintCode\ Trial.app/Contents/Info.plist | grep BundleName
```

output:

```
"CFBundleName" => "PaintCode Trial"
```

Comment: This does seem a viable alternative.  These Bundle Identifiers will be more difficult to remember and longer to type.  For Foxit, the Bundle Identifier is `com.foxitsoftware.FoxitReaderLite`.  If there is not a way to get the shorter application name, a bash alias for this would probably be the next best option, i.e., `alias foxit="open -b com.foxitsoftware.FoxitReaderLite"`.

Comment: @stvn66 I've added the info about getting the app name in my answer.

Comment: Why go through so much rigamarole when simply `open -a "Foxit Reader" /path/to/file.pdf` does what the OP is asking!?

Comment: Because some apps have different display name than bundle name. For example it could be Localized.

Comment: Good point! +1 :)